# Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $cordovaSmsProvider <- $cordovaSms <- smsController

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am trying to send SMS using  cordova-sms-plugin with ionic but I am getting an error.I tried all the possible answers from this site but still an issue has not resolved.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="lib/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">
  <ion-pane ng-controller="smsController">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
      <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>

    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label" style="padding-top: 50px" >Number</span>
          <input type="number" ng-model="sms.number">
        </label>

        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">Message</span>
          <input type="text" ng-model="sms.message">
        </label>

        <button class="button button-full button-positive" ng-click="sendSms()">
          Send
        </button>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-pane>
    <!--<ion-pane>-->
      <!--<ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">-->
        <!--<h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>-->
      <!--</ion-header-bar>-->
      <!--<ion-content>-->
      <!--</ion-content>-->
    <!--</ion-pane>-->
  </body>
</html>
```

aap.js

```
.controller('smsController',["$scope", "$cordovaSms",function($scope,$cordovaSms){
    $scope.sms={};

    var options = {
        replaceLineBreaks: false, // true to replace \n by a new line, false by default
        android: {
            intent: 'INTENT'  // send SMS with the default SMS app
            //intent: ''        // send SMS without open any other app
        }
    }

        $scope.sendSms=function(){
        console.log($scope.sms.number);
        console.log($scope.sms.message);

        $cordovaSms
            .send($scope.sms.number, $scope.sms.message, options)
            .then(function() {
                // Success! SMS was sent
                console.log('Success');
            }, function(error) {
                // An error occurred
                console.log(error);
            });//then
    }//sendSms

}]);
```

This is my module

```
var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ngCordova'])
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
```

Can anyone please help me how should I resolve this error?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is a regular Angular error when you forgot a step while installing ngCordova. Please follow http://ngcordova.com/docs/install/.

Comment: show your module that may help you

Comment: Ok I have added module to my question

Comment: @Shweta http://ngcordova.com/docs/install/ check this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine. The only problem which could cause the `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:` error are:

1. Either you have not loaded `ngCordova` module as dependency, (which you already have done) or
2. `lib/ng-cordova.min.js` script file is not in the right path and not getting downloaded.

Ensure that these 2 issues are not there in your console and your code should work

Comment: What was the exact error? I guess it was the file path not being correct

Comment: yes.ng-cordova.min.js  was in another folder.so it was giving an error.

Comment: Can you tell if i want to do this for sending multiple sms then how to do?